# Unable to list AWS SQS metrics

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I am trying to list all the available metrics under namespace "AWS/SQS" but getting empty response. To make sure this is not a permission issue i had even tried with Admin Access/Secret key

```
    ListMetricsRequest mq = new ListMetricsRequest();
    mq.setNamespace("AWS/SQS");
        System.out.println(cw.listMetrics(mq).getMetrics().size());
```

I am able to vie this metrics using chrome via AWS UI.
Any pointers to the solution will really help
Regards,
Amit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing a mistake. Was not specifying the region correctly